# How can I create a bar graph from this Dataframe?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

I have this dataframe (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRD1H.jpg) that I created from an SQL query. I want to create a bar graph that shows the frequency for each type of movie genre, so I can see what the top genre is.

My problem is that in the genre column, each value is compromised of multiple genres. But I want to separate each into its own genre. So say I have a movie whose genre is "Action, Thriller". I want to be able to count those as two separate entries.

I have been trying to work on this for days, but for the life of me I cannot figure out syntax to be able to do this. Should I do the actual separating in my SQL query, or should I do it when working with the DF? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BeRT2me I tried making a new column of whether a movie was a certain type of genre (action) and doing a bar graph with that, but couldn't figure out how to do frequencies. I also tried just straight up bar graphing with genre and averagerating as variables, but it just looks messy, thus why I want to separate them. Did the same thing with genre and numvotes, but again it came out looking very messy.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't seen SQL in a long time, so I can't say about it.

But in python, I would do something like this:

```
def count_genre(genre_array):

    genre_array_sep = []
    counts = []
    for g in genre_array:
        genre_array_sep.append(g.split(", "))
    # print(genre_array_sep)

    options = ["Thriller", "Drama", "Action"]
    for op in options:
        count = 0
        for g in genre_array_sep:
            if op in g:
                count += 1
                g.remove(op)
        # print(genre_array_sep)
        counts.append(count)

    return counts

# input
film_genre = ["Thriller", "Drama", "Action, Thriller", "Action", "Action"]
# output
print(count_genre(film_genre))
```

But please bear in mind that I'm not a programmer so there is certainly a better/faster solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response Eva! Turns out there is a very easy solution of using .split() and .explode() on the Dataframe to solve the problem!

Comment: But then you have the same movie multiple times in the data frame, if it has multiple genres, don't you mind?

Comment: Not necessarily, because I just created a separate DF and used that to graph. I still kept the original DF

Comment: Well, that makes sense. ;)